# Is it possible to set the background color of a google spreadsheet cell with a formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know about conditional formatting, but I'd like to be able to specify the **color with the formula**. I'm designing some color fade algorithms and am calculating the RGB values in a spreadsheet. I'd like to put my 3 R, G, and B values in columns and have the 4th column show the color.

Answer (score 4):

Not with formulas, an `onEdit`on Apps Script could do that, but wouldn't be efficient:

```
function componentToHex(c) {
    var hex = c.toString(16);
    return hex.length == 1 ? "0" + hex : hex;
}

function rgbToHex(r, g, b) {
    return "#" + componentToHex(r) + componentToHex(g) + componentToHex(b);
}

function onEdit(){
  var RGBVals = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues(),
      backSet = [],
      currLin;

  for( lin in RGBVals ){
    currLin = RGBVals[ lin ];
      backSet.push([rgbToHex(currLin[0], currLin[1], currLin[2])]);
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1, 4, backSet.length).setBackgrounds(backSet);
}
```

Note: R,G,B in A,B,C column, starting in ROW 1.

Comment: The efficiency of the `onEdit()` would be vastly improved if instead of looping over the whole range it used the event passed to it to isolate just the changed row.