# Google Spreadsheet: Keep formatted data from INDIRECT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying myself with my first complex Google Spreadsheet! *yaay* But I am lost now and asking you all for help; here is my case description:

- Google Spreadsheet: "complexa"

  - Sheet1: "Results"

    - dependend dropdown with data validation "DataStorage"!"one""two"
  - Sheet2: "DataStorage"

    - named ranges "one" and "two"

Within "DataStorage" I collect my data, calculate and format it via formulae (text color changes, background color changes based on value = / >= / < through conditional formatting).

Two ranges with data are made through named ranges.

Within the "Results" sheet I am then displaying the data via dropdown by using =INDIRECT("dropdownCell").

My Problem: The displayed data range from "DataStorage" in "Results" is not formatted at all. I would like the background and font colors from the "DataStorage" sheet.

Can anyone help me out with this problem? :-) Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to set the background color of a google spreadsheet cell with a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036012/is-it-possible-to-set-the-background-color-of-a-google-spreadsheet-cell-with-a-f)

Comment: No sadly not :( because there the RGB is made out of actual cell values whereas I need the same background and font color of many cells in the process of doing the "=INDIRECT" functionality from a dropdown choice which loads a range from another sheet.

Answer (score 0):

From the question

> Within "Results" I am displaying the data from the dropdown via =INDIRECT("dropdownCell").
>
> My Problem: The displayed data in "Results" is not formatted at all. I would like the background and font colors from the "DataStorage" sheet.

Formulas will not show the background and/or font colors.

In order to get these attributes automatically you might use a trigger created using Google Apps Script.

Related

- [Is it possible to set the background color of a google spreadsheet cell with a formula?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30036012/1595451)
- [Setting the cell's background color with a custom function (script)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39576458/1595451)

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: I am going to look into this ASAP and will answer you shortly :)

Comment: Sorry, the related answers you gave are all with the color code written into the cell itself, so the color is made out of the cell value given. I think I am more in need of a kinda VLOOKUP with the source having a color set through conditional formatting, which I need to take over to the result.